# Fullcalendar v5 - Problems with EventClick and Select

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm blocked with a problem on full Calendar.
I have a calendar initialized with and `initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth'`, And I want to be able to add an event with a click on a cell. But i also want to delete an event on click on
So, I add `selectable: true` to can add an event with :

```
select: function(event) {
  calendar.addEvent({
     title: '',
     start: beginDate,
     resourceId: personId,
     end: endDate,
     backgroundColor: 'red',
     display: 'background'
  });
}
```

That works well, but if I click on an existing event (to delete it) it's impossible to trigger `eventClick`, I think it's due to a conflict between `select` and `eventClick`. But I can't resolve it.

Comment: It’s not necessary to say ‘I look forward to your response’ on stack overflow, but I appreciate you were trying to be nice :) Just from a stylistic point of view, it’s better to just focus on the content of the question.

Comment: @TREBUA `a conflict between select and eventClick`...this makes no sense. These two things are not related. eventClick happens when you click on an event. select happens when you click on an empty area of the calendar. Turning on selections does not prevent clicking on events. You must have a different problem. Please make us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e. show us enough code that we could paste it in and run it, and it would demonstrate your problem. Otherwise we can't really help you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at eventClick!
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Where you can implemente your custom "delete" function related to eventID

Comment: It's already the event I use but when I click on an event, the ```eventClick``` is not Trigger due to the ```selectable``` option is true

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: No code at all to look after your problem? If solve, please add +1 to my answer.